# Jekyll Compatibility with .erb

Tags: ruby, yaml, erb, jekyll, liquid

From my understanding, Jekyll is compatible for use with Liquid and YAML. However, is there a plugin or available functionality that allows it to be compatible with .erb (embedded Ruby) files?

Otherwise, Is this a functionality rendered unnecessary or something that is otherwise not useful? Does Jekyll's built-in usage of Liquid and YAML replace what .erb would or could do?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try the [jekyll-rendering](https://github.com/blackwinter/jekyll-rendering) gem?

Comment: I have not! I was wondering if the functionality is built in. If it's a plug-in I'm after, that just may answer my question. Thanks!

Comment: Jordan, functionality to use .erb files is not built into Jekyll. You'll have to use a plugin. @SunnyJuneja, it looks like you should add your comment as an answer so Jordan can choose it if that's what he ends up using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `.erb` is not plausible with jekyll, however you should use the [jekyll-rendering](https://github.com/blackwinter/jekyll-rendering) gem.

Comment: Jordan, I believe there is no technical hurdle in using erb (as there is a gem for it) but just the preference of the author to use liquid as the templating engine.